# Routing issue CodeIgniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes

i have link

http://www.raffaello-test.com/static/frontend/deutsch/mode-bilder/mode-herren-krawatten/gianni-versace-herren-krawatten.jpg

but i need to hide "/static/frontend" remove this part from URL and get get image from this URL

http://www.raffaello-test.com/deutsch/mode-bilder/mode-herren-krawatten/gianni-versace-herren-krawatten.jpg

i think it will be from .htaccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the option is to create a symlink in the document root.

Second option is to use htaccess rewrite rule. Something like the following should work fine:

```
RewriteRule ^((deutsch|english)/.+/.+/.+\.(jpe?g|png|gif))$ /static/frontend/$1 [L]
```

If you have more languages just add them in first parenthesis, like `(deutsch|english|russian)`.

Also note that It's not recommended to use rewriting in high load production for static content, better use symlinks